# How to send user and password auth to a legacy in OSB 12c?

Tags: authentication, wsdl, soa, osb

I'm making a proxy service in OSB 12c and I'm going to a legacy that implements user and password authentication. From SoapUI I can send that info from "Properties" fields, but I don't know how to send that from OSB. I guess it could be sent from Business Service file but not sure. I searched on google but I found info about how to implement usr and psw on my proxy service, but not how to send that info to a external WSDL.

[image]

I'm getting 401 error from legacy when I try to consume the WSDL through SB console. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are existing policies that can do this in 12c. Atleast in 11g there weren't.

You have to manually create and add the HTTP header that make outgoing basic authentication possible.

Wiki about basic authentication header: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side

In OSB you can add this by using the 'Transport Header' step on the outbound request.
How it looks in OSB: [image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use basic authentication is by using the owsm policy instead of manipulating transport header.